# xxxClass defined in org.koin.android.ext.android

Tags: koin

The same class can rely on injection if it USES get() or by inject() in an activity, but if it is not used in an activity, it will report an error when injecting. Why?

error:

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun  ComponentCallbacks.get(qualifier: Qualifier? = ..., noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? /* = (() -> DefinitionParameters)? */ = ...): xxClass defined in org.koin.android.ext.android

Comment: Did you implement KoinComponent in your class? Please provide a code sample for more information

Comment: thanks ， implement KoinComponent

Comment: You're welcome! I have added a more detailed answer on why this happens. If you think this could help others. please click the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to inject koin objects in your classes, you need to implement the KoinComponent interface ([see documentation here](https://start.insert-koin.io/#/getting-started/koin-components?id=the-koincomponent-interface))

The reason you could use `by inject()` or `get()` in Activities and Fragments directly without implementing KoinComponent is because Koin does that automatically for you! It leverages the power of extension functions so that they are considered a KoinComponent.